# Switch как преобразовать задачу?

Tags: javascript, switch

Господа, как сделать с помощью switch на javascript такую программу:

```
<html>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">  
x = prompt ("Введите балы","");

if ( x >=0 && x <= 40 ){  
    alert ("Fx отчислен");  
}
else if ( x >=41 && x <= 59){  
    alert ("F, На пересдачу!");  
}
else if ( x >= 60 && x <= 67 ){  
    alert ("E, 3-");  
}
else if ( x >= 68 && x <= 74 ){  
    alert ("D, 3");  
}
else if ( x >= 75 && x <= 81 ){  
    alert ("C, 4-");  
}
else if ( x >= 82 && x <= 90 ){  
    alert ("B, 4");  
}
else if ( x >= 91 && x <= 100 ){  
    alert ("A, 5");  
}

</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

У нас спор! Именно на джаваскрипт и только со свитч!

Comment: Гуглить пробовали?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994135/javascript-switch-using-intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что изначальный пример написан крайне плохо. Хотя бы так, например:

```
if (x >= 0) {
    if (x < 41) {
        alert("Fx");
    } else if (x < 60) {
        alert("F");
    } else if (x < 68) {
        alert("E");
    } else if (x < 75) {
        alert("D");
    } else if (x < 82) {
        alert("C");
    } else if (x < 91) {
        alert("B");
    } else if (x < 101) {
        alert("A");
    }
}
alert("Error");
```

Можно и через switch...

```
switch ((x < 0) + (x < 41) + (x < 60) + (x < 68) + (x < 75) + (x < 82) + (x < 91) + (x < 101)) {
    case 1: alert("A"); break;
    case 2: alert("B"); break;
    case 3: alert("C"); break;
    case 4: alert("D"); break;
    case 5: alert("E"); break;
    case 6: alert("F"); break;
    case 7: alert("Fx"); break;
    default: alert("Error!"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(true) {
    case(x<0):
        m = "ниже плинтуса"
        break;
    case(x<41):
        m = "Fx отчислен";
        break;
    case(x<60):
        m = "F, На пересдачу!";
        break;
    case(x<68):
        m = "E, 3-";
        break;
    case(x<75):
        m = "D, 3";
        break;
    case(x<82):
        m = "C, 4-";
        break;
    case(x<91):
        m = "B, 4";
        break;
    case(x<101):
        m = "A, 5";
        break;
    default:
        m = "Чо, самый умный?!";
}
alert(m);
```